# How can I add ':include_blank => true' to customized select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I'd like to add this option

> :include_blank => true

How can I add it to this select_tag?

```
 <%= select_tag :genre, options_for_select(Genre.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this in the documentation:

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select something"
```

So you use :prompt => "blank prompt"

Yours might look like this:

```
select_tag :genre, options_from_collection_for_select(Genre.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }, "id", "name"), :prompt => "Select something"
```

Documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html 
Look at select_tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `include_blank` with `select_tag`.

From the documentation:

```
select_tag "people", options_from_collection_for_select(@people, "id", "name"), :include_blank => true

# => <select id="people" name="people"><option value=""></option><option value="1">David</option></select>
```

Or you can use `options_for_select`:

```
<%= select_tag column.name, options_for_select(Genre.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
```